# JNI method help. Memcpy with destination offset

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, buffer, native

I am making a Jni replacement method for FloatBuffer.put(), since on Android 2.x and below, the FloatBuffer.put() method is inefficiently implemented as stated [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wiki/index.php/Direct_Bulk_FloatBuffer.put_is_slow). However, I want to be able to able to put a given array of src floats to a specified offset in the dst floatbuffer, as I could with position() and put(). With this in mind, I implemented this JNI method.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_voidseer_voidengine_mesh_Vertices_PutFloatsJni
(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jfloatArray src, jobject dst, jint numFloats, jint dstOffset )
{
        float* pDst = (float*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress( dst );
        float* pSrc = (float*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(src, 0);

        memcpy( pDst + (dstOffset << 2), pSrc, numFloats << 2 );

        env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(src, pSrc, 0);
}
```

However, something seems wrong. My game engine does not draw my entities like it should. Can someone spot something wrong I am doing here in this function?

Thanks

EDIT:

Just got it to work with this code.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_voidseer_voidengine_mesh_Vertices_PutFloatsJni
(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jfloatArray src, jobject dst, jint numFloats, jint dstOffset )
{
        float* pDst = (float*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress( dst );
        float* pSrc = (float*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(src, 0);

        memcpy( &pDst[dstOffset], pSrc, numFloats << 2 );

        env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(src, pSrc, 0);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Please post the working code as an answer, and accept it once you can.

Comment: Cool, I will look into it... Yeah pretty strange. According to the Float.SIZE static variable in Java the Size is 4 bytes so it should be four bytes. Also, I made a JNI method that simply returned sizeof(float) which also returned 4 bytes. I changed the method above memcpy size argument to sizeof(float) * numFloats, too. No effects though on that part.

Comment: I think  "&pDst[dstOffset]" is equivalent to "pDst + dstOffset". C/C++ uses pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with this code.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_voidseer_voidengine_mesh_Vertices_PutFloatsJni
(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jfloatArray src, jobject dst, jint numFloats, jint dstOffset )
{
        float* pDst = (float*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress( dst );
        float* pSrc = (float*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(src, 0);

        //memcpy( pDst + (dstOffset << 2), pSrc, numFloats << 2 );
        memcpy( &pDst[dstOffset], pSrc, sizeof(float) * numFloats );

        env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(src, pSrc, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy( pDst + (dstOffset << 2), pSrc, numFloats << 2 );
```

The first `<< 2` is incorrect. Remove it. The C compiler will automatically adjust the increment based on sizeof *pDst.

EDIT: the second shift should be `* sizeof float`.

The validity of the article you linked to and its benchmarks of non-working code are pretty dubious.

Comment: Well, I first heard of the issue from an Android programming book and on some Android developer groups as well. So I assume it its better to be on the safe side. Plus, I got to learn about JNI and NDK : ].

Comment: @MichaelWojcik My point is that as the code didn't work, any benchmarks deriving from it are worthless.